# where is the unexpected character?

Tags: python

```
dcm.set(\["Motion/Position/Sensor/LAnklePitch", "Merge", \[[1.0,dcm.getTime(10000)]] ])
```

no spaces after the last ")"

```
unexpected character after line continuation character: C:\Users\ady\Desktop\untitled-1.py, line 12, pos 88
```

Comment: You should provide a complete example that we could help more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a backslash at the start, after `dcm.set(`. You can only use that at the *end* of a line, where it is called the line continuation character. You have another one after the `"Merge",` string.

You don't need to 'escape' the square brackets here, nor do you need to use line continuations inside parentheses *anyway*.

The following should work, for example:

```
dcm.set([
    "Motion/Position/Sensor/LAnklePitch", "Merge",
    [[1.0, dcm.getTime(10000)]]
])
```

Comment: thanks.. that was the exact line of code aldebaran put up on their documentation.. i just changed the Motion/Position/Sensor/LAnklePitch

Comment: @ady: they probably had newlines in the original source right after those backslashes, which may have been lost somewhere. The backslashes are not needed at all even if there were newlines however.